# Non-Enumerable properties showing in `for...in` loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In my understanding, `for ...in` *statement iterates over all* ***enumerable*** *properties of an object*  (source:[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in))

Then, how come the global `navigator` object in the BOM, for instance, responds as follows:

```js
for (prop in navigator) { 
  console.log(prop);
}

//OUTPUT:
//vibrate 
//javaEnabled
//....
```

Even though, all the properties printed in the console return `false` against `document.propertyIsEnumerable('prop')`. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: You mean you checked it with `navigator.propertyIsEnumerable("custom")` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms my bad; I was trying to grok it and added a property called custom. I have removed it now. No I checked against the default properties of the navigator object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable):

> The propertyIsEnumerable() method returns a Boolean indicating whether the specified property is enumerable **and is the object's own property**.

As you can show with `Object.getPrototypeOf(navigator)`, some of the properties are not owned by the navigator itself, but are inherited from it's prototype.

```js
const example = Object.create({ you: "see" });

for(let key in example) console.log(`enumerable key: ${key}`);

console.log(`'you' is own and enumerable: ${example.propertyIsEnumerable("you")}`);
console.log(`'you' is own property: ${example.hasOwnProperty("you")}`);
```

Comment: Thanks; I am close to grasping it fully I think. So, the properties are of navigator are not enumerable (as per the MDN ref), but then as per the MDN link in the question, `for...in` should pick up only enumerable properties. Doesn't that mean one of the premises is wrong?

Comment: Maybe they are enumerable, just not part of the object itself?

Comment: How do I go about checking that? I don't think `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` can help me in this case.

Comment: @DaveIdito well it does, cause it won't give you a descriptor back if it is inherited.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the explanation.